# I need to remove MSRP label in WooCommerce Product Page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to remove the "MSRP" label in WooCommerce. I have looked everywhere and cannot find why it's happening. Tried display: none; in CSS for that tag but it removes the price as well, which I want to stay.

[What I Want To Remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zuZU.png)

If anyone has experience with this, please let me know. I'm wracking my brain. I didn't develop this website. Is it a WooCommerce setting that I'm somehow not finding?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to modify your template or using `display:none`? If not, this should remove the text line.

```
.price.product-page-price .product-page-regular-price { display:none; }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I entered that in a custom CSS field and it removed the price and the "MSRP" label, where I only need the "MSRP" label removed.

Comment: then just use span before .product-page-regular-price. i think your regular price is set under that `del` tag

Comment: So,

.product-page-regular-price span{ display: none; }

I did try this but that had the same effect

Comment: no. `.price.product-page-price span.product-page-regular-price { display:none; }`